# Quitting a job to take another job

Tags: job-change, job-offer

I am in a big company right now. I got a job offer at a smaller company. I am not sure whether to take it. What are some things to consider before making a decision? Are there advantages and disadvantages of a small company over a larger company?

Comment: Depends entirely on your needs.  Can you identify what you want that your existing employer doesn't offer?

Comment: Hey oore, and welcome to the Workplace! I think the question I linked should give you some information on a big company vs. a smaller company. If there is something specific in there that doesn't address your concerns, could you please edit your question to focus on a specific issue? Thanks!